# perl split and regular expressions case in-sensitve

Tags: perl

I have a have a string where the seprator is word and is case insenstive something like this

Data1 sep Data2 Sep date 3 SEP Data4 SeP Data 5

i am writing something like this :

```
split /(sep|SEP|Sep|seP)/, $string
```

is there an option to list split to split data incase sensitve ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument in [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), for the separator, is a normal regex so

```
my $sep = 'sep';

my @fields = split /$sep/i, $string;
```

will split the string by `sep` case-insensitively (on any of `sep`, `sEP`, etc).

---

Easy try:

```
perl -wE'$str = q(heysephosEpho); say for split /seP/i, $str'
```